# Payara no more supports RMI. Right?

Tags: payara

my company wants to migrate from WebLogic to Payara Server.

As far as I understand Payara no longer supports RMI Communication. Right?

Comment: How do you come to this conclusion? As far as I know remote EJB calls are done using RMI and they are supported.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. As you know Oracle WebLogic will be discontinued. My company is now migrating to Payara. Do you think there will be a problem ??

Comment: Well this largely depends on your application and the used APIs. If you used something specific to WebLogic you might run into problems

Answer (score 1):

Payara Server 5 supports complete Jakarta EE 8 functionality, including calling remote EJBs over RMI. Payara even compiled a [migration guide from WebLogic](https://docs.payara.fish/community/docs/5.2021.1/documentation/payara-server/ejb/lite-remote-ejb.html) and provides a lot of resources to help you migrate from WebLogic.

There are no plans to drop any RMI-related features in Payara Server.

There are new features developed and planned that can be used as an alternative if you RMI protocol isn't suitable for you to invoke remote EJBs, but they're not going to replace the RMI support. Payara Server currently supports calling [remote EJBs over HTTP](https://docs.payara.fish/community/docs/5.2021.1/documentation/payara-server/ejb/lite-remote-ejb.html). It's still in technical preview and doesn't support all the functionality that RMI supports. Payara also plans to support [remoting over the gRPC protocol](https://blog.payara.fish/payara-roadmap-2021) in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Payara Server (as Glassfish successor) is fully compatible with both Java EE:

https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/compatibility-jsp.html

and Jakarta EE:

https://jakarta.ee/compatibility/#tab-one

including RMI, ofcourse.

Moreover, Payara Server Full and Payara Micro are compatible with Microprofile as well:

https://wiki.eclipse.org/MicroProfile/Implementation

(note that Microprofile does not include RMI)